# Flutter how to force Timer to cancel?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a timer that is called from a button OnPressed: startTimeOut(60).

```js
startTimeout(mins) async {

  await subscription.resume();
  print("susbscription started");
  return new Timer(Duration(minutes: mins), handleTimeout);
}
void handleTimeout() async {
    await subscription.cancel().then((_) {

      print("susbscription canceled");
    });
```

But the user has the possibility to abort the subscription stream by calling startTimeOut(0). In this case "susbscription canceled" get's printed but the first timer call is still active, so the subscription goes on merrily till the 60 minutes are over. Then "susbscription canceled" is printed again.

How could I sort of overwrite/cancel the first call to Timer?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep a reference to the `Timer` instance and call [`cancel`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Timer/cancel.html) on subsequent calls to `startTimeout`.

Comment: Thank u Nate. Thing is that's exactly what I'm having trouble in doing. Tried to put it in a variable, so I could do something like varTimer.cancel() in the timeOut, but the compiler does not accept something like: return new varTimer(Duration(minutes: mins), handleTimeout);

Comment: Declare the variable with `Timer timeout;`. Assign with `timeout = Timer(...); return timeout;`. The variable with need to be in a scope outside of  `startTimeout` - without knowing more context it's hard to say if it needs to be global or if there is some class in which it can be an field... You might want to read through the language tour: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour

Comment: pls check out my modified code with the timeout var u suggested.

Comment: Not sure why you have an `await` on the call to `subscription.pause()` - that should return `void`... Assigning a global var like that should work, there must be something missing in the context here.